# Failure while running flutter

Tags: flutter

I'am trying to run my flutter app on my android device but everytime
I try to run it I'am getting an error but the things is that the flutter
app is a newly created flutter project and I haven't run any code
yet but the android device is the one I always use to run my flutter apps
this is the error:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on SM G9250 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
F/CoreApps(23818): [1][CommonFeature] ###versionCode : 115082101, CONTACT_PROFILE_SERVICE_ENABLE : true, FREE_MESSAGE_ENABLE : true
F/CoreApps(23818): [1][CommonFeature] ###versionCode : 115082101, CONTACT_PROFILE_SERVICE_ENABLE : true, FREE_MESSAGE_ENABLE : true
F/CoreApps(23818): [ELog][1][EasySignUp] [NotRegistered][014dade2924475c9ae5e0ed07254fa66fa9f1650bb]
F/CoreApps(24071): [1][CommonFeature] ###versionCode : 115082101, CONTACT_PROFILE_SERVICE_ENABLE : true, FREE_MESSAGE_ENABLE : true
F/CoreApps(24071): [1][CommonFeature] ###versionCode : 115082101, CONTACT_PROFILE_SERVICE_ENABLE : true, FREE_MESSAGE_ENABLE : true
F/CoreApps(24071): [ELog][1][EasySignUp] [NotRegistered][014dade2924475c9ae5e0ed07254fa66fa9f1650bb]
F/CoreApps(24352): [1][CommonFeature] ###versionCode : 115082101, CONTACT_PROFILE_SERVICE_ENABLE : true, FREE_MESSAGE_ENABLE : true
F/CoreApps(24352): [1][CommonFeature] ###versionCode : 115082101, CONTACT_PROFILE_SERVICE_ENABLE : true, FREE_MESSAGE_ENABLE : true
F/CoreApps(24352): [ELog][1][EasySignUp] [NotRegistered][014dade2924475c9ae5e0ed07254fa66fa9f1650bb]
F/CoreApps(24586): [1][CommonFeature] ###versionCode : 115082101, CONTACT_PROFILE_SERVICE_ENABLE : true, FREE_MESSAGE_ENABLE : true
F/CoreApps(24586): [1][CommonFeature] ###versionCode : 115082101, CONTACT_PROFILE_SERVICE_ENABLE : true, FREE_MESSAGE_ENABLE : true
F/CoreApps(24586): [ELog][1][EasySignUp] [NotRegistered][014dade2924475c9ae5e0ed07254fa66fa9f1650bb]
F/Finsky:background(25198): [62819] kce.h(3): Service object is not present when stopServiceSafely was called.
F/Finsky:background(25198): com.google.android.flib.log.WhatATerribleException
F/Finsky:background(25198):     at adil.h(PG:2)
F/Finsky:background(25198):     at com.google.android.finsky.utils.FinskyLog.k(PG:3)
F/Finsky:background(25198):     at kce.h(PG:3)
F/Finsky:background(25198):     at kce.g(PG)
F/Finsky:background(25198):     at kce.e(PG:2)
F/Finsky:background(25198):     at kcp.h(PG)
F/Finsky:background(25198):     at kcn.a(PG:4)
F/Finsky:background(25198):     at kcp.j(PG:1)
F/Finsky:background(25198):     at kcp.c(PG)
F/Finsky:background(25198):     at jzy.e(PG:12)
F/Finsky:background(25198):     at jzv.apply(PG:117)
F/Finsky:background(25198):     at j$.util.stream.s.accept(SourceFile:45)
F/Finsky:background(25198):     at j$.util.a.forEachRemaining(SourceFile:20)
F/Finsky:background(25198):     at j$.util.stream.c.y(SourceFile:21)
F/Finsky:background(25198):     at j$.util.stream.c.G(SourceFile:8)
F/Finsky:background(25198):     at j$.util.stream.Z0.e(SourceFile:1)
F/Finsky:background(25198):     at j$.util.stream.c.J(SourceFile:35)
F/Finsky:background(25198):     at j$.util.stream.A1.collect(SourceFile:83)
F/Finsky:background(25198):     at jzm.a(PG:57)
F/Finsky:background(25198):     at akic.e(PG:2)
F/Finsky:background(25198):     at akie.run(PG:9)
F/Finsky:background(25198):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
F/Finsky:background(25198):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
F/Finsky:background(25198):     at htq.run(PG:40)
F/Finsky:background(25198):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
F/Finsky:background(26867): [62984] kce.h(3): Service object is not present when stopServiceSafely was called.
F/Finsky:background(26867): com.google.android.flib.log.WhatATerribleException
F/Finsky:background(26867):     at adil.h(PG:2)
F/Finsky:background(26867):     at com.google.android.finsky.utils.FinskyLog.k(PG:3)
F/Finsky:background(26867):     at kce.h(PG:3)
F/Finsky:background(26867):     at kce.g(PG)
F/Finsky:background(26867):     at kce.e(PG:2)
F/Finsky:background(26867):     at kcp.h(PG)
F/Finsky:background(26867):     at kcn.a(PG:4)
F/Finsky:background(26867):     at kcp.j(PG:1)
F/Finsky:background(26867):     at kcp.c(PG)
F/Finsky:background(26867):     at jzy.e(PG:12)
F/Finsky:background(26867):     at jzv.apply(PG:117)
F/Finsky:background(26867):     at j$.util.stream.s.accept(SourceFile:45)
F/Finsky:background(26867):     at j$.util.a.forEachRemaining(SourceFile:20)
F/Finsky:background(26867):     at j$.util.stream.c.y(SourceFile:21)
F/Finsky:background(26867):     at j$.util.stream.c.G(SourceFile:8)
F/Finsky:background(26867):     at j$.util.stream.Z0.e(SourceFile:1)
F/Finsky:background(26867):     at j$.util.stream.c.J(SourceFile:35)
F/Finsky:background(26867):     at j$.util.stream.A1.collect(SourceFile:83)
F/Finsky:background(26867):     at jzm.a(PG:57)
F/Finsky:background(26867):     at akic.e(PG:2)
F/Finsky:background(26867):     at akie.run(PG:9)
F/Finsky:background(26867):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
F/Finsky:background(26867):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
F/Finsky:background(26867):     at htq.run(PG:40)
F/Finsky:background(26867):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: It's strange that you are seeing errors in the log before running any code in your newly created Flutter project.

Comment: open your android folder in android studio so it will start sync & build gradle process,  check its correctly build or not so if yes then try flutter clean & run again or not then check error from android studio console.

Comment: please can you explain it to me better